# How do I remove 1 property without changing object, so I can add content to tablecells?

Tags: javascript, html

**Contents:**

- Problem
- Error I get
- Code
- Data
- What I want

**Problem:** 
Trying to fill out tablecells that have ID's however I have 1 too many properties in my object, how do I remove this without altering the object? I want the rest of the code to use this object in it's whole.

**Error I get:** 
"TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null"

**Code:** 
(Trying to shorten it, so it will be easier to help, however I might miss some necessary code please notify me!)

```js
function processResponse(response) {
  var responseJS = JSON.parse(response);
  // Squad information:
  Object.keys(responseJS).forEach(key => {
    let tablecellID = document.getElementById(key);
    tablecellID.innerHTML = responseJS[key];
  });
}
```

```css
td {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
```

```html
<table id='overview-table'>
  <tr>
    <th>squadName</th>
    <th>homeTown</th>
    <th>formed</th>
    <th>secretBase</th>
    <th>active</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id='squadName'></td>
    <td id='homeTown'></td>
    <td id='formed'></td>
    <td id='secretBase'></td>
    <td id='active'></td>
  </tr>
  <table>
```

**Data:** 
So this is the JSON data, maybe seeing the data structure will help.

```
{
  "squadName" : "Super Hero Squad",
  "homeTown" : "Metro City",
  "formed" : 2016,
  "secretBase" : "Super tower",
  "active" : true,
  "members" : [
    {
      "name" : "Molecule Man",
      "age" : 29,
      "secretIdentity" : "Dan Jukes",
      "powers" : [
        "Radiation resistance",
        "Turning tiny",
        "Radiation blast"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name" : "Madame Uppercut",
      "age" : 39,
      "secretIdentity" : "Jane Wilson",
      "powers" : [
        "Million tonne punch",
        "Damage resistance",
        "Superhuman reflexes"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name" : "Eternal Flame",
      "age" : 1000000,
      "secretIdentity" : "Unknown",
      "powers" : [
        "Immortality",
        "Heat Immunity",
        "Inferno",
        "Teleportation",
        "Interdimensional travel"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**What I want to get:** 
The code works, however I want to get rid of the error and make the rest of the code work.
Here's the bit where the Squad works;
[![Squad table working][1]][1]

Here's the part where the Member bit works:
[![Member table working][2]][2]

**Want these two to work at the same time.**

Feel free to ask for additional information.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G86nY.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTuje.png

Comment: When the key equals to `members`, the `tablecellID` is null.

Comment: @GyDi Good catch! How do I fix that then? Because I have no idea. I can't alter the object itself, because I have to use it in later stages of the program as a whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply limit the key-processing to the first 5 keys by using `.slice(0,5)`:

```js
const squadron=`{"squadName" : "Super Hero Squad","homeTown" : "Metro City","formed" : 2016,"secretBase" : "Super tower","active" : true,"members" : [
    {"name" : "Molecule Man","age" : 29,"secretIdentity" : "Dan Jukes","powers" :["Radiation resistance","Turning tiny","Radiation blast"]},
    {"name" : "Madame Uppercut","age" : 39,"secretIdentity" : "Jane Wilson","powers" : ["Million tonne punch","Damage resistance","Superhuman reflexes"]},
    {"name" : "Eternal Flame","age" : 1000000,"secretIdentity" : "Unknown","powers" : ["Immortality","Heat Immunity","Inferno","Teleportation","Interdimensional travel"]}]}`;
function processResponse(response) {
  var responseJS = JSON.parse(response);
  // Squad information:
  Object.keys(responseJS).slice(0,5).forEach(key => {
    let tablecellID = document.getElementById(key);
    tablecellID.innerHTML = responseJS[key];
  });
}
processResponse(squadron);
```

```css
td {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
```

```html
<table id='overview-table'>
  <tr>
    <th>squadName</th>
    <th>homeTown</th>
    <th>formed</th>
    <th>secretBase</th>
    <th>active</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id='squadName'></td>
    <td id='homeTown'></td>
    <td id='formed'></td>
    <td id='secretBase'></td>
    <td id='active'></td>
  </tr>
  <table>
```

If the order of keys cannot be guaranteed then the following will be safer:

```js
const squadron=`{"squadName" : "Super Hero Squad","homeTown" : "Metro City","formed" : 2016,"secretBase" : "Super tower","active" : true,"members" : [
    {"name" : "Molecule Man","age" : 29,"secretIdentity" : "Dan Jukes","powers" :["Radiation resistance","Turning tiny","Radiation blast"]},
    {"name" : "Madame Uppercut","age" : 39,"secretIdentity" : "Jane Wilson","powers" : ["Million tonne punch","Damage resistance","Superhuman reflexes"]},
    {"name" : "Eternal Flame","age" : 1000000,"secretIdentity" : "Unknown","powers" : ["Immortality","Heat Immunity","Inferno","Teleportation","Interdimensional travel"]}]}`;
function processResponse(response) {
  var res = JSON.parse(response);
  // Squad information:
  Object.entries(res).forEach(([key,val]) => {
    let td = document.getElementById(key);
    if(td) td.innerHTML=val;
  });
}
processResponse(squadron);
```

```css
td {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
```

```html
<table id='overview-table'>
  <tr>
    <th>squadName</th>
    <th>homeTown</th>
    <th>formed</th>
    <th>secretBase</th>
    <th>active</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id='squadName'></td>
    <td id='homeTown'></td>
    <td id='formed'></td>
    <td id='secretBase'></td>
    <td id='active'></td>
  </tr>
  <table>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Will this alter the object in a way that I can't use it in it's whole in later stages of the program? (Pardon for poor wording!).

Comment: `.slice()` will create a copy by "slicing off" a few elements from the original array and will leave the original array unchanged.

Comment: thank you for the great help and explanation, it worked. Awesome + very informative.

Comment: This solution will not work if the key order get changed in the json response from backend.

Answer (score 1):

You are mostly doing it right here, there is only one change you'll need to make, to ensure that `element` has a value:

```
function processResponse(response) {
  var responseJS = JSON.parse(response);
  // Squad information:
  Object.keys(responseJS).forEach(key => {
    let tablecellID = document.getElementById(key);
    if(tablecellID)  { // check if element exists
      tablecellID.innerHTML = responseJS[key];
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you add a bit more information as to what you did here and how it works?

Comment: @Lar `if(tablecellID)  tablecellID.innerHTML = responseJS[key];` this is the important change. Before assign value to innerHTML he checks if tablecellID actually exists.

Comment: @MazedulIslam have updated the answer with the explanation